# React. Как уменьшать значение таймера в localstorage на единицу?

Tags: reactjs, localstorage, react-hook, таймер

Как уменьшать значение таймера в localstorage на единицу? Использовал хук 'useLocalStorage', но значение на единицу динамически так и не уменьшается

Сам таймер:

```
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useLocalStorage('timer',  5 * 60)

    const getPadTime = (time) => time.toString().padStart(2, '0')

    const minutes = getPadTime(Math.floor(timeLeft / 60))
    const seconds = getPadTime(timeLeft - minutes * 60)

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimeLeft((timeLeft) => (timeLeft >= 1 ? timeLeft - 1 : setDisabled() ||  5 * 60))
        }, 1000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval) 
    }, [])
```

Данные хука 'useLocalStorage':

```
import {useState} from 'react'

function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
    // State to store our value
    // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
      if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        return initialValue;
      }
  
      try {
        // Get from local storage by key
        const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
        return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
      } catch (error) {
        // If error also return initialValue
        console.log(error);
        return initialValue;
      }
    });
  
    // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
    // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
    const setValue = (value) => {
      try {
        // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
        const valueToStore =
          value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
        // Save state
        setStoredValue(valueToStore);
        // Save to local storage
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
          window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
  
    return [storedValue, setValue];
  }

  export default useLocalStorage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему путём установки npm пакета `use-local-storage`. Пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-hodgkin-9e76q4?file=/src/App.js